# MySQL: Number of messages per week per user since join

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing the following columns:

table:
message_id,
user_id,
message_date,
user_join_date

I need to present number of messages per each user in each week since the date they have joined till current date (week_1, week_2 , ... week_N).

I found I could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(message_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(message_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(message_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3,
    .....
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(message_date) = N THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_N
FROM table
WHERE message_date >= user_join_date
  AND message_date <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

But the problem is that it`s not a dynamic method as number of weeks are not fixed and might change and also the code would be very long if even import numbers manually.

So, I was wondering if this is even possible in MySQL to have a dynamic approach? Or I have to use something like python for that.

Please let me know if further clarification is required.

Thanks.

I have used manual method, but need to have a dynamic approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT user_id,WEEK(message_date),COUNT() AS N 
FROM table 
WHERE message_date>=user_join_date AND message_date<=CURDATE() 
GROUP BY user_id,WEEK(message_date) 
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Where N is the number of messages.

Comment: if this can't help you, please provide the table definition. I might be more helpful knowing the db structure.